# How to preserve tab state when using NavigationExperimental on react-native?

Tags: react-native, uitabbar

I am building an app with tab bar using react native's NavigationExperimental API based on the [example](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/NavigationExperimental/NavigationTabsExample.js) from github.

One thing I noticed is that tabs' UI states are not preserved when switching between tabs.

All state including fetched data, scroll position, other UI states, etc., are lost when I switch away from one tab to another.

As a result, it ends up refetching the data, and renders everything from the scratch.

The only thing that is preserved is the current navigation state tree.

This is not true for native apps. Native apps keep every state (data, scroll position and other UI states) so that the switch feels instant and lightweight avoiding any network calls or re-renderings.

How can this be implemented in react native?

I was thinking hiding and showing like `display: 'none'`, but `display` is not available in react-native.

Comment: That is not good.  I am trying to replace a tab control where each tab has it's own instance of **NavigatorIOS** with **NavigatorExperimental**.  I am having a hard time getting started with **NavigatorExperimental**.     I cannot get the **UIExplorer** to run:      [react-native UIExplorer will not run in iOS simulator? ( red-box “No script URL provided” )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396001/react-native-uiexplorer-will-not-run-in-ios-simulator-red-box-no-script-url)