# react-native UIExplorer will not run in iOS simulator? ( red-box "No script URL provided" )

Tags: react-native

Using Xcode 7.3, I get "No script URL provided" running on an iOS simulator?

I followed [UIExplorer README.md](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/UIExplorer)

```
git clone https://github.com/facebook/react-native.git
cd react-native
npm install
Open Examples/UIExplorer/UIExplorer.xcodeproj in Xcode
Hit the Run button
```

[image: react-native UIExplorer red-box "No script URL provided"]

Usually running on iOS simulator runs well.  What am I missing?

My goal is to evaluate NavigatorExperimental in UIExplorer for use on both iOS and Android.

Other examples such as /Examples/Movies/ run fine.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

This recent change broke running of UIExplorer:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/913b4ccee492780ae180657094c261805455deea

Work-around is to comment-out the following lines in AppDelegate.m.

Commenting-out prevents it from setting the sourceURL = nil

```
// if (!getenv("CI_USE_PACKAGER")) {
// sourceURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
// }
```

The Movies example works fine. The Movies example does not have this line checking for CI_USE_PACKAGER environment variable.